# How to send multiple data fields via Ajax to php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem, I want to send 2 posts to my author php page by using ajax

thats my code :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/get_competitions.php",
data:'sport=<?php echo $_GET['sports']; ?>',
success: function(data){
    $("#competitions-list").html(data);
}
```

and this what i want to do :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "includes/get_competitions.php",
data:'sport1=<?php echo $_GET['sports1']; ?>, sport2=<?php echo $_GET['sports2']; ?>',
success: function(data){
    $("#competitions-list").html(data);
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: "but it didn't work" Could you be more specific ?

Comment: in the first code it worked but in the second no data has been send i need to know the right way to do it

Comment: `data: {sport: <?php echo $_GET['sports']; ?>, sport2: <?php echo $_GET['sports2']; ?>},`

Comment: thank you it is working

Comment: you should still serialize it, then you don't have to type in every name

Comment: You can pass complex object by using it like `$.ajax({ type: 'POST', url: 'includes/get_competitions.php', data: { sport1: "value of sport 1", sport2: "value of sport 2", success: ...})` See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ for documentation.

Comment: `echo json_encode(['sport1'=>$_GET['sports1'], 'sport2'=>$_GET['sports2']]);` - Use Json, that is what it is after all.  As a side note you can also use `http_build_query` for query type strings, such as URL query strings etc...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix PHP won't automatically parse JSON into `$_POST` elements.

Comment: @Barmar - not sure what you mean as what I put is going from PHP array, to some other string format.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Oh, I see what you're saying. I missed that it was a PHP assoc array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple parameters in a data string are separated by `&`, not `,` (it's just like the syntax of parameters in a URL).

However, if you're using jQuery it's best to use an object. `$.ajax` will automatically convert it to the properly encoded query string. And you can use `json_encode()` to convert a PHP value to the corresponding JavaScript literal.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/get_competitions.php",
    data: {
        sport1: <?php echo json_encode($_GET['sports1']); ?>, 
        sport2: <?php echo json_encode($_GET['sports2']); ?>
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#competitions-list").html(data);
}
```

You could also make a single `sports` array, rather than numbering the parameters.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/get_competitions.php",
    data: {
        sports: [<?php echo json_encode($_GET['sports1']); ?>, 
                 <?php echo json_encode($_GET['sports2']); ?>]
    },
    success: function(data){
        $("#competitions-list").html(data);
}
```

Then in `get_competitions.php`, `$_POST['sports']` will be an array.

Comment: Aw - beat me too it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize()   <---- your form name
```

This will send all the form data

Comment: This works great if the OPs data is coming from a form. But if it is coming from a parameter from the url, as the OP is using `$_GET`, then this doesn’t work